# Pass empty cell value from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I have a datagridview of 14 column that are partially/fully fill with number and character, most of the time they are partially fill.

What I try to do is pass those values into a .csv file.  Problem is, the code I wrote didn't pass over empty cell and crash.  I want every cell value separated with a comma and when all column of the row have been scan, pass to the next row until the end of the grid.

Data should appear like this: 1945.9,1260.4,P3.P4,,,,,,,,,,2018-07-17 08:17:27

[image: Datagridview]

The code I have so far look like this:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim date_rapport As Date = Date.Today
    Format(date_rapport, "dd-MM-yyyy")

    Dim filePath As String = "C:\Rapport_punch" & date_rapport & "\" & ".csv"
    Dim delimeter As String = ","
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 0 To data_punched.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim array As String() = New String(data_punched.Columns.Count - 1) {}
        If i.Equals(0) Then
            For j As Integer = 0 To data_punched.Columns.Count - 1
                array(j) = data_punched.Columns(j).HeaderText
            Next
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delimeter, array))
        End If
        For j As Integer = 0 To data_punched.Columns.Count - 1
            If Not data_punched.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                array(j) = data_punched(j, i).Value.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If Not data_punched.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delimeter, array))
        End If
    Next
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString)
    'Opens the file immediately after writing
    Process.Start(filePath)
End Sub
```

I think I need to work in this part of the code, but didn't know how.

```
 For j As Integer = 0 To data_punched.Columns.Count - 1
            If Not data_punched.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                array(j) = data_punched(j, i).Value.ToString
            End If
 Next
```

Any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check first if it's null (can't check this as I don't have a set-up in this machine), it's probably the problem.

```
For j As Integer = 0 To data_punched.Columns.Count - 1
        If Not data_punched.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
            If (data_punched(j, i).Value == null) Then
                array(j) = ""
            Else
                array(j) = data_punched(j, i).Value.ToString
            End If
        End If
 Next
```

Comment: Your the man!! I've juste changed the "Value == null" by "Value = nothing"